# varchar entry of 5118 causing SQL Server stored procedure to fail

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, triggers

and thanks in advance

I have a very basic stored procedure that inserts a row into a table. It has been working flawlessly until today

Here is the script

```
(
@emp varchar(16),
@logdate date,
@logtime time,
@term char(20),
@SSID char(16)
)
AS
INSERT INTO AccessLog (EmployeeID, LogDate, LogTime, TerminalID, InOut, ChangedBy) 
VALUES (@emp, @logdate, @logtime, @term, 3, @SSID)
```

When the string of 5118 is passed to it the insert will fail. There are several triggers that fire after this insert finishes.

Here's the strange part. You can pass it anyother number for the `@emp` variable and it works just fine, but pass it 5118, it fails.

The error I receive is below:

> *Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Procedure UpdateTimeWorked, Line 27
>
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
>   string.*

Here is the procedure that is failing – the highlighted line is Line 27

```
TRIGGER [dbo].[UpdateTimeWorked] ON [dbo].[TimeLog]
FOR UPDATE
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @ID int;
DECLARE @RCDIDIN int;
DECLARE @RCDIDOUT int;
DECLARE @ComboIn datetime;
DECLARE @ComboOut datetime;
SELECT @ID = ID FROM INSERTED;
SELECT @ComboIn = LoginCombo FROM INSERTED;
SELECT @ComboOut = LogoutCombo FROM INSERTED;
SELECT @RCDIDIN = RCDIDIN FROM INSERTED;
SELECT @RCDIDOUT = RCDIDOUT FROM INSERTED;

**IF ( UPDATE(LogoutCombo))**
BEGIN
    IF (@RCDIDOUT != 0)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE TimeLog
            SET LogOutRND = (select CAST(dbo.roundtime(LogOutRND,0.25) AS TIME))
            WHERE ID = @ID
        UPDATE TimeLog
            SET LogOutComboRND = CAST(CAST(LogOutDate AS DATE) AS SMALLDATETIME) + CAST(LogOutRND AS TIME)
            WHERE ID = @ID
        UPDATE TimeLog
            SET TimeWorked = dbo.gettime(DATEDIFF(ss,LogInComboRND,LogoutComboRND))
            WHERE ID = @ID AND LogInEntered = 1 AND LogOutEntered = 1
        UPDATE TimeLog
            SET TimeWorked = (select CAST(dbo.roundtime(TimeWorked,0.25) AS TIME)), Rounded = 1
            WHERE ID = @ID AND LogInEntered = 1 AND LogOutEntered = 1
    END
END

IF ( UPDATE(LoginCombo))
BEGIN
    IF (@RCDIDIN != 0)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE TimeLog
            SET LogInRND = (select CAST(dbo.roundtime(LogInRND,0.25) AS TIME))
            WHERE ID = @ID
        UPDATE TimeLog
            SET LogInComboRND = CAST(CAST(LogInDate AS DATE) AS SMALLDATETIME) + CAST(LogInRND AS TIME)
            WHERE ID = @ID
        UPDATE TimeLog
            SET TimeWorked = dbo.gettime(DATEDIFF(ss,LogInComboRND,LogoutComboRND))
            WHERE ID = @ID AND LogInEntered = 1 AND LogOutEntered = 1
        UPDATE TimeLog
            SET TimeWorked = (select CAST(dbo.roundtime(TimeWorked,0.25) AS TIME)), Rounded = 1
            WHERE ID = @ID AND LogInEntered = 1 AND LogOutEntered = 1
    END
END


GO
```

I am at a total blank to come up with why this is not working.

Anyone have any ideas?

Like I stated, pass it any other entry for the @emp and it will run fine. I can even pass it ‘5118’ and it will work, but not 5118.

Comment: Your trigger is broken for multi row inserts.

Comment: Besides the fact that this trigger won't work if more than one row is inserted/updated..I would check what you have in the column that you are converting to a date in your tables for ID 5118..it looks like a string that can't be converted to a date

Comment: Also wanted to point out, you're inserting into table `AccessLog`, but the trigger is for the table `TimeLog`.   I assume AccessLog has some trigger that in turn affects TimeLog?

Comment: Clarify a bit. 5118 is an employee number, and is assigned to the variable @emp.
Any other employee number fed into the script will pass through all the triggers and work, but 5118 will not. Tried 5116 5117 5119 4118 all worded fine. One the first insert is finished if fires another trigger that copied the same information into another exact table. From there a trigger fires to match entries to create a one line entry into another table so we have an employees clock in and out and the time worked gets calculated.

Comment: Martin Smith - could you please explain what I should change in my trigger so it is not broken for multi row inserts?

Comment: @MichaelRochel - The `INSERTED` table can contain many rows (or no rows at all in fact) but you are assigning the values from it to a scalar variable (assuming that there will always be one row). I doubt it will be possible for anyone to answer the rest of your question as the trigger you have posted bears no relation to the initial table so it is not possible to see what `EmployeeID` in the first table has to do with the second trigger.

Comment: I'm concerned about 4 updates happening when 1 per case would suffice?